# Horizontal Scroll Array of JSON Objects

Tags: arrays, json, scroll, processing, p5.js

Ok so i have the results from the JSON array all lined up nicely. They dont seem to move across the screen though. Is it because my txtX = 0; is still in draw? Ive played around but cant seem to remedy this and as a result, still have static text :-(

```
var scores;
var txtX;
var txtY;

function preload() {

scores = loadJSON("stats.json");

}

function setup() {

createCanvas(700, 700);

}

function draw() {

background(254);
var txtX = 0;
var txtY = 550;
var stats = scores.results;
for (var i = 0; i < stats.length; i++) {
textSize(12);
text(stats[i], txtX, txtY);
var wordWidth = textWidth(stats[i]);
var currentOffset = 15;

txtX = txtX + wordWidth + currentOffset;

}

txtX = txtX - 1;


}
```

Here is my JSON:

```
{
"description" : "FA Cup results; 7th January 2017.",
"source" : "http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/results",
"results":[
"Manchester United 4-0 Reading",
"Accrington Stanley 2-1 Luton Town",
"Barrow 0-2 Rochdale",
"Birmingham City 1-1 Newcastle United",
"Blackpool 0-0 Barnsley",
"Bolton Wanderers 0-0 Crystal Palace",
"Brentford 5-1 Eastleigh",
"Brighton & Hove Albion 2-0 Milton Keynes Dons",
"Bristol City 0-0 Fleetwood Town",
"Everton 1-2 Leicester City",
"Huddersfiled Town 4-0 Port Vale",
"Hull City 2-0 Swansea City",
"Ipswich Town 2-2 Lincoln City",
"Millwall 3-0 Bournemouth",
"Norwich City 2-2 Southampton",
"Queens Park Rangers 1-2 Blackburn Rovers",
"Rotherham United 2-3 Oxford United",
"Stoke City 0-2 Wolverhampton Wanderers",
"Sunderland 0-0 Burnley",
"Sutton United 0-0 AFC Wimbledon",
"Watford 2-0 Burton Albion",
"West Bromwich Albion 1-2 Derby County",
"Wigan Athletic 2-0 Nottingham Forest",
"Wycombe Wanderers 2-1 Stourbridge",
"Preston North End 1-2 Arsenal"
]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does this code do? What exactly is wrong about it?

Comment: Ok,  i need them to scroll across the screen with an even space between them. I want them to move onto screen from off screen right and scroll to off screen left and then repeat that. At the moment they are all piled on top of one another but i can seem to make them not do that...

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot about your code that doesn't make sense:

- Why are you using a nested `for` loop? Your inner `for` loop seems to iterate over each word in an individual string. Why not just pass the whole string into the `text()` function instead of each word one at a time?
- Why are you only changing `currentOffset` after that inner loop completes? You're drawing a whole string but only changing the offset for a single word.
- Why are you adding `500` to the `currentOffset`?
- Why don't you ever use the `txtX` variable?

You need to take a step back and rethink exactly what you're doing. If I were you, I would do the following:

- You need to keep track of two variables: the `txtX` variable at the sketch level that keeps track of the start, which scrolls to the left, and a `currentWordX` variable that keeps track of the offset of the current string relative to the `txtX` variable.
- You only need a single `for` loop. Even if your eventual goal requires drawing each word separately, start with a single `for` loop that iterates over the `results` array.
- For each string in the `results` array, you draw that string. Its X position is `txtX + currentWordX`. Then you get that string's width and add that value to the `currentWordX` variable.
- After the `for` loop, you need to decrease the `txtX` variable to cause the whole thing to scroll to the left.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I tend to experiment with different ideas and my code gets a little confused as a result. I will take your advice on board and try to get my head around this. Thanks.